# Container View Not Moving Off Screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a container view that I want to initially be off the bottom of the screen. It should be easy, but I seem to be missing something fundamental. I have previously done something similar by moving controls off the left side of the screen with:

```
control.center.x -= view.bounds.width
```

I have a very simple storyboard setup:

[image]

And my view controller looks like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        containerView.center.y += view.bounds.height
    }
}
```

When run, the container view is right where it shows in the storyboard and is not offscreen. Even setting the containerView's center.y to a specific value such as `containerView.center.y = 50` will do nothing. The only way I can get it to show off screen is by adding animation in the viewDidAppear:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
   super.viewDidAppear(animated)
   UIView.animateWithDuration(0, animations: {self.containerView.center.y += self.view.bounds.height})
}
```

But that just seems like a workaround and not the proper way to do it. I have been dealing with this for hours, reading blogs, reading other Stackoverflow questions, but I cannot find the solution. I do not have constraints on the container, although I did test it with constraints and that did not make a difference. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the main view's `layoutSubviews is called after you reposition the container view, so it will default to the position specified in the storyboard.

The proper way to do is to have proper layout constraints in storyboard, make an outlet for the bottom edge constraint and set this constraint's `constant` property.

Comment: Thank you! I modified viewWillAppear to this
        `containerViewBottomConstraint.constant = -containerView.frame.height` and now it works as expected.